# difference between 伴 and 配

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

I am reading a restaurant menu in Chinese and found the usage of 伴 and 配 perplexing. What is the rule? (Or is there?)

For example: 咖喱燒雞配印度薄餅及印度飯 and 蘋果批伴雲呢拿汁

Answer (score 3, accepted):

伴 - accompany

配 - complement

XX 伴 YY means XX and YY are served together as a **single dish**. 蘋果批伴雲呢拿汁 means 蘋果批 and 雲呢拿汁 are to be eaten together

XX 配 YY (or more) means XX and YY (or more) are served together as a **single set**. 咖喱燒雞配印度薄餅及印度飯 has three items, 咖喱燒雞 is the main dish and 印度薄餅 and 印度飯 are the side dishes in the set.

The additional item  that is 配 to the main dish is considered a side dish

You can have 咖喱燒雞 配 土豆湯 或 雜菜湯, but you cannot have 咖喱燒雞 伴 土豆湯 或 雜菜湯 because they are not considered a single dish.

Comment: If translating a menu in English to Chinese, which would we use in, say, "Sirloin steak served with new potatoes and seasonal greens"?, and "Pepperoni pizza"?

Comment: 沙朗牛排配新土豆及时令蔬菜. You can eat the steak, potato, and vegetable separately, therefore, the potato and vegetable are side dishes (complement) ; Pepperoni pizza (意大利辣香肠比萨饼)  is a single dish

Comment: A typical breakfast, 火腿、煎蛋、牛油吐司  are three side dishes; But we would say 肉醬意大利粉 配 煎蛋 及 牛油吐司 because 肉醬意大利粉 is the main dish

Comment: Regarding  肉醬意大利粉, (which of course means spaghetti with a meat sauce), which is a dish where you eat the spaghetti together with the meat sauce, (just like pepperoni pizza where you eat the meat topping together with the "pizza dough"), it should be technically correct to say  肉醬(伴)意大利粉, or pizza with multiple toppings like 橄榄,蘑菇和番茄(伴))比萨?

Comment: it is technically correct to say 肉醬(拌)意大利粉 (not 伴),  And 肉醬意粉 would be less wordy; 橄榄,蘑菇和番茄(伴)比萨 is incorrect because Olives, mushrooms and tomatoes are Ingredients  that are part of the pizza